# How to do simple arithmetic calculator in django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to show two sets of number from model in the django template for the same. I am using for loop to get each row data of the table to show in template as below :

{% for a in vis %}

{a.numone}
{a.numtwo}

{% endfor %}

its working fine!.

Now, I want to do simple arithmetic calculation by using this numbers. say for example add, sub, div, multiply this two number and show it in template.

How to do it?

Question Updated below:

Model.py

```
class visits(models.Model):
doctor = models.ForeignKey(doctorprofile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
patient = models.ForeignKey(patientprofile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)



visit_cons_fee = models.DecimalField(null=False, blank=False,  max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
visit_other_fee = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

def total_fee(self):
    return (self.visit_cons_fee + self.visit_other_fee)

def __str__ (self):
    return str(self.id)
```

views.py

```
vis=visits.objects.filter(patient=patid).values( 'visit_cons_fee','visit_other_fee', 'doctor__doc_Fname', 'doctor__doc_Lname' )
```

template as below:

{% for a in vis %}

Consultation Fees : {% if a.visit_cons_fee %}{{a.visit_cons_fee}}{% else %} 0 {% endif %}

Other Fees : {% if a.visit_other_fee %}{{a.visit_other_fee}}{% else %} 0 {% endif %}

Total Fees : ????

{% endfor %}

Comment: Do that in the _view_ or maybe in a method on your model. Django deliberately makes this difficult in an attempt to separate business and presentation logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Generic way

The template is not designed for any calculation or modification of data. It is used just for showing the data in the prefered way.

As all template need a view in django, just place the calculation in the view instead.

`views.py`

```py
def your_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # ... your code
    vis = visits.objects.filter(patient=patid)
    for a in vis:
        a.calculated_value = make_calculation(a)
    context = {'vis': vis}
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', context)
```

`your_template.html`

```html
{% for a in vis %}
  {{ a.numone }} {{ a.numtwo }} {{ a.calculated_value }}
{% endfor %}
```

#### Values are coming from the same model object

If the values for the calculation are coming from the same model instance, you could just add a method or property to your model and use this in your template.

`models.py`

```py
class ModelA(models.Model):
    # ... your code
    @property
    def calculated_value(self):
        return (self.numone + self.numtwo * 2) / 25
```

`your_template.html`

```html
{% for a in vis %}
  {{ a.numone }} {{ a.numtwo }} {{ a.calculated_value }}
{% en
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, in my case numbers are comes from the same table. I have tried to do as you mentioned but it not return any value:                             @property
    def total_fee(self):
        return (self.visit_cons_fee + self.visit_other_fee)

Comment: @SaravananRagavan could you show the template markup you used? And the completed Model you used? (Please update your original question with the details)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have updated my question with view, model and template. Please check and advice.

Comment: You should not use `.values()` as this will return only a list of values, instead of a list of objects, which is what you need to work with the methods and properties of the model.

Comment: even I remove .values(), I am getting error as unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'NoneType'

Comment: This is an issue with your calculation method. Try changing your line to `return ((self.visit_cons_fee or 0) + (self.visit_other_fee or 0))`

Comment: Thanks a ton!. Its working great!. but without using values, I am missing some values which I am getting from other table by using foreign key. do you have any solution for it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246186/discussion-between-saravanan-ragavan-and-janmalte).